# Can't enable logs for Google Cloud Logging

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Container Engine and trying to add logs like in this guide
http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/logging/

There are no logs in logging console,
but many messages like this in fluentd pod log

-> kubectl logs -f --tail=5 fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-we-production-da3a3de4-node-s285 --namespace=kube-system
  2016-06-14 17:51:21 +0000 [warn]: suppressed same stacktrace
2016-06-14 17:51:28 +0000 [warn]: temporarily failed to flush the buffer. next_retry=2016-06-14 17:51:58 +0000 error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError"
 error="The caller does not have permission" plugin_id="object:f9a9ac"

What does permissions it want? Please help me, I really stuck on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the fluentd pod is unable to write to the google cloud logging api endpoint. To write logs, the VM must have the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write` scope on the VM's default service account.

Comment: You is right! In IAM on Compute service account I have added Logger write permission. But it's strange and not obvious because then I was creating a "container cluster" the Logging write permission was set by default. I thought is shares for all container hosts

Comment: But now I see kubernetes logs without any container logs. May be you now why is that?

Comment: All logs have appeared after I restart fluentd pod. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad that fixed it for you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue now.

From Gcloud Command Console.

1. Check your IAM policy

> $gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-name] --format json

2. Add the following permissions to the user login.

> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME]
> --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/viewer
>
> ```
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.viewer
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.logWriter
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.configWriter
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.bucketWriter
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.viewAccessor
>
> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-NAME] --member=user:[Login-email-ID] --role=roles/logging.admin
> ```